# Unable to understand query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working on an SSIS job that contains a complex query.

It has some thing like :

```
 some sql statements

 left outer join

 (
    select query joining two more tables )

 table1
```

here, i am unable to understand what that table1 mean ? Is it a kind of temporary view

created . This table1 is used in the other parts of query . But, actually the table1 does

exists in the database.

Is it like , the results of the select query in the parenthesis is created as table1

Please clarify me on this..

I am not able to put down my code because of Security Policies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table1` is an *alisas* your subquery. It's the name of subquery you can use with columns for example `table1.col1`

Comment: Yes..I thought the same..But just wanted to clarify..thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

**[Here is SQL Fiddel example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/14284/8)**

**Below is the sample query**

```
Select Temp1.id,Table1.id Table1_id
  from Temp1
  left Outer join 
       (
         Select Temp2.id 
           from Temp2
           join Temp3
             On Temp2.id = Temp3.id
       ) Table1

    on Temp1.id = Table1.Id
```

In above example `table1` is the Alias for data coming from `joins`of two tables (`temp2` and `temp3`)

Answer (score 1):

It is an alias for the query in the parenthesis.

If you would remove that you would get an error.

Aliases are also good when you have the same column in more than on joined tables, so you can distinquish them.

For instance if colX is both in Table1 and Table2 you would have a query like:

```
SELECT T1.colX,T2.colX
FROM   Table1 T1
       JOIN Table2 T2
           ON T1.id = T2.id
```